# locally Euclidean of manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, solution-verification, smooth-manifolds

If  manifold M (without boundary) ,if for some point $p\in M$ has a neighborhood homeomorphic to a open set $\phi(U)\subset \mathbb{R}^n$.Prove it also exists a neighborhood homeomorphic to (topology) interior of $\mathbb{H}^n$

My attempt:Since for some point $p\in M$ has a neighborhood homeomorphic to a open set $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$,we can first find a neighborhood homeomorphic to a ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$(since for $\phi(p) \in U =\bigcup B_\alpha$ exist a $B_\alpha$ such that $\phi(p) \in B_\alpha$ so with open set $U_p = \phi^{-1}(B_\alpha)$,chart $(U_p,\psi=\phi)$  is the chart that we want).since $\psi(U_p) = B_\alpha$ is bounded.

For this new chart$(U_p,\psi)$ we can translate $\psi(U_p) = B_\alpha$ into $\mathbb{H}^n$ by adding some bounded constant on the last coordinate.

**Is my proof correct? Or is the proposition above incorrect?So exist some counter example?**

(By the way does this mean that we can claim that if $p$ in the interior chart $(U,\phi)$,we can always find another char $(U'_p,\psi)$ to be the one that $\psi(U'_p)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{H_+}^n$ instead of $\phi(U)$ open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ )

Comment: Is H^n not homeomorphic with R^n?

Comment: @JakeMirra I believe $\Bbb H^n$ refers to the half-space, but OP wasn't complete. All that the OP really needs to say is the OP's final statement: The open half-space (i.e., its interior) is globally homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin , Hi,to make my question more clearly, For a local chart of the manifold, i.e. $(U,\phi)$ we can always map $\phi(U)$ to open set in open half-space? I found somewhere make this statement but not in the textbook

Comment: Yes, just compose the usual chart with the homeomorphism from $\Bbb R^n$ to the interior of $\Bbb H^n$.

Comment: thanks ,intuitively,$e^x$ is one the homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R} \to $ interior of $\mathbb{H}$ correct?